Log only "direct path" of range
Title is a rather imprecise attempt at an "intuitive" description. What I really want is:  to specify a range of commits, but ignore commits that are not descendants of the excluded commit, i.e. that are not on a path from the base of the range to the tip of the range.
For example, suppose you're working on a branch, which during its history merges some other branch, and that other branch starts from a different baseline than your feature:
* e821b45 - (HEAD -> feature) feature commit (1 second ago) <Brendan Jackman>
*   c5b9ab7 - Merge branch 'dependency' into feature (4 seconds ago) <Brendan Jackman>
|\  
| * 0296ba0 - (dependency) dependency commit (22 seconds ago) <Brendan Jackman>
| * d332c6c - dependency commit (23 seconds ago) <Brendan Jackman>
| * 5844b6b - dependency commit (24 seconds ago) <Brendan Jackman>
* | 8bd2613 - feature commit (8 seconds ago) <Brendan Jackman>
* | 7e2679c - (tag: base, main) base (58 seconds ago) <Brendan Jackman>
|/  
* 429c8cf - hello (61 seconds ago) <Brendan Jackman>
* eda7b8f - hello (62 seconds ago) <Brendan Jackman>


Normally if you want to look at your work on feature you'd run git log [...] base..feature, but in this case it will also show all the dependency commits that you don't care about:
* e821b45 - (HEAD -> feature) feature commit (2 minutes ago) <Brendan Jackman>
*   c5b9ab7 - Merge branch 'dependency' into feature (2 minutes ago) <Brendan Jackman>
|\  
| * 0296ba0 - (dependency) dependency commit (2 minutes ago) <Brendan Jackman>
| * d332c6c - dependency commit (2 minutes ago) <Brendan Jackman>
| * 5844b6b - dependency commit (2 minutes ago) <Brendan Jackman>
* 8bd2613 - feature commit (2 minutes ago) <Brendan Jackman>

How do you specify only the commits that are on the path between base and feature?

This is what the --ancestry-path flag does. From the manpage:
       --ancestry-path[=<commit>]
           When given a range of commits to display (e.g.
           commit1..commit2 or commit2 ^commit1), only display commits in
           that range that are ancestors of <commit>, descendants of
           <commit>, or <commit> itself. If no commit is specified, use
           commit1 (the excluded part of the range) as <commit>. Can be
           passed multiple times; if so, a commit is included if it is
           any of the commits given or if it is an ancestor or descendant
           of one of them.

This flag exists for multiple commands, e.g. as well as git log, you can use this for git rev-list. So I think it's probably a pretty general solution. But I'll leave the question open in case someone knows a way to do this that's more like just a "range expression" instead of a command flag.
If feature and dependency had the same base, this would not work. I think the only solution there would be to take advantage of the knowledge of the way the merge commits got created: because you were presumably sitting on feature and ran git merge dependency, your feature branch will be the "left side" of the merge. So you can use --first-parent.

if feature and dependency have the same base you want a symmetric range, three dots: feature...base. See git help revisions.
